# Windows Phone Whatsapp .DB

Tags: whatsapp

I have windows phone WhatsApp .db files which are messages.db, calls.db and settings.db. I want to view the messages and calls data. How is it possible?
Can anyone please help me. Thanks in advance. 
By the way, I have tried whatsapp_xtract and it gives an error that input string must be of length 16. Help me, please.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with the Windows Phone platform

Comment: @kelvinelove I believe that this question is on topic because It deals about a problem specific to Windows phone OS. Whatsapp in other OS does not store the db files separately for Messages, call, etc... In Android there will be just a single msgstore.db file. This question refers to a Windows Phone in particular.

Comment: @KolappanNathan But isn't the **.db** format universal. I mean, its an SQLite database, which is the same thing irregardless of platform. The problem is more of a database file format issue, rather than being a Windows Phone platforms specific issue...!!!

Comment: @kelvinelove .db is a universal format. But I believe *how to open whatsapp chat files in Windows Phone?* is a valid question and it is only applicable to Windows Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you download "WINAPP CRACK 2.0" from http://www.netup.in. This small program is available as a shareware and can process messages.db and calls.db files upto size of 1kb and unlimited when the premium version is purchased. It will show you all the messages with call records in a chronological order for all the backups prepared by Windows Whatsapp Mobiles. Try.